# Finding isomorphism between two structures - question

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

I have the next structures: $M_1=(\mathbb{Q}\cap(0,1),<)$ and $M_2=(\mathbb{Q},<)$, and I need to find if they are isomorphic. Now, I know that they have the same cardinality and thus, there is a bijection, however, I don't see an isomorphic function satisfies the ratios, e.g. $h(x)=\frac{1}{x}$, from $M_1$ to $M_2$. So  I think they aren't isomorphic, but I cannot find a sentence which one satisfies and the other doesn't.

Comment: You'll want to use a different criterion for a counterexample in general (there isn't a counterexample in this case). Non-isomorphic structures can satisfy exactly the same sentences.

Comment: @MaliceVidrine but in this question I was asked giving a sentence, provided as a counterexample, such that one structure satisfies and the other satisfies the negation of the the sentence.

Comment: @asd123 The structures $M_1$ and $M_2$ are isomorphic. So either that question is wrong, or you did not quite paraphrase the question correctly. Are you maybe given an explicit function and asked to show that that is not an isomorphism?

Comment: @MarkKamsma It was my attempt. I was asked to show if they are isomorphic or not. If so I need to prove, otherwise to give a sentence.

Comment: @MarkKamsma can you tell me what function satisfies that they are isomorphic?

Comment: Hint: look at the graph of $-\frac{x}{x^2-1}$. This function won't establish the right kind of bijection by itself, but it can be adjusted to do what you need.

Comment: @asd123: It is also possible to prove that they are isomorphic without finding a formula for a concrete isomorphism. One can use a [back and forth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Back-and-forth_method) construction to show that **any** two dense linear orders without endpoints are isomorphic.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott So this means that I can directly say by that, that since they are countably infinite, without endpoints and they have the ratio - <, then they are immediately isomorphic?

Comment: @asd123: Only if you’ve actually proved that all countable dense linear orders without endpoints are isomorphic. (Note that although I inadvertently omitted it in my previous comment, the restriction to **countable** linear orders is essential.)

Comment: @BrianM.Scott So it isn't necessarily true for uncountable set, alike the real numbers?

Comment: @asd123: Correct. For example, $\Bbb R$ and $\Bbb R\setminus Q$ are both dense linear orders without endpoints, and they have the same cardinality, but they are not isomorphic as linear orders, because every bounded subset of $\Bbb R$ has a least upper bound in the order, but this is not the case for $\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Do you have another methods for checking isomorphic right away like this method, because I will be glad see.

Comment: @asd123: Not really, I’m afraid; I’ve just had a lot of practice working with linear orders.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott oh I see. But thank you so much!!! You have helped me a lot with that.

Comment: @asd123: You’re very welcome.